# HKStatisticsCollectionQuery for fetching Heart Rate Health Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I have been trying for a while for fetching heart rate in order to plot in a graph. As mentioned in docs heart rate can be fetched by HKStatisticsCollectionQuery. I am trying to fetch a week's data from current date.

But I am unable to get the fetched data. Here is my code below for heart rate accessing using HKStatisticsCollectionQuery :

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *interval = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSDate *anchorDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateComponents *anchorComponents =
    [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth |
     NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSDate *currentDisplayEndDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *newDate = [calendar startOfDayForDate: currentDisplayEndDate];  NSDate *startDate = [newDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-6*24*60*60];
anchorDate = startDate;
 NSPredicate *predicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:self.startDate endDate:_currentDisplayEndDate options:HKQueryOptionStrictStartDate];

HKQuantityType *quantityType =
    [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:quantityId];

    // Create the query

    HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query =
    [[HKStatisticsCollectionQuery alloc]
     initWithQuantityType:quantityType
     quantitySamplePredicate:predicate
     options:HKStatisticsOptionDiscreteMax
     anchorDate:anchorDate
     intervalComponents: interval];

    // Set the results handler
    query.initialResultsHandler =
    ^(HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query, HKStatisticsCollection *results, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            // Perform proper error handling here
            NSLog(@"*** An error occurred while calculating the statistics: %@ ***",
                  error.localizedDescription);
        }
        [results
 enumerateStatisticsFromDate:startDate
 toDate:endDate
 withBlock:^(HKStatistics *result, BOOL *stop) {

     HKQuantity *quantity = result.sumQuantity;
     if (quantity) {
         NSDate *date = result.startDate;
         double value = [quantity doubleValueForUnit:[[HKUnit unitFromString:@"count/min"]];

         // Call a custom method to plot each data point.
     }

 }];
    };

    [healthStore executeQuery:query];
```

My `HKStatistics *results` is returned as nil.Am I doing something wrong over here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem in not where you thought, The results are returned with statistical query, but in case of heart rate, it does not give heart beat quantity along with that, so `HKQuantity *quantity = result.sumQuantity;` returns nil.

If you will check properly, you will see that `results.statistics` will give you some data about recorded heart rate, but no heart rate quantity, rather only, the start and end dates for the recorded data.

I would suggest, go ahead and  you `HKAnchoredQuery` for the same, I will provide the code, here:

```
-(double)get_heartRates
    {
    //code to heart beats average, modify as needed
    NSDate *startDate1 = [NSDate distantPast];
    NSPredicate *Predicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:startDate1 endDate:[NSDate date] options:HKQueryOptionStrictEndDate];
    HKSampleType *object = [HKSampleType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate];

    sum_Of_HeartRates=0.0;

    HKAnchoredObjectQuery  *heartQuery = [[HKAnchoredObjectQuery alloc] initWithType:object predicate:Predicate anchor:self.lastAnchor limit:0 resultsHandler:^(HKAnchoredObjectQuery *query, NSArray<HKSample *> *sampleObjects, NSArray<HKDeletedObject *> *deletedObjects, HKQueryAnchor *newAnchor, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Sample counts:%ld",sampleObjects.count);
        for(int i=0;i<(int)sampleObjects.count;i++)
        {
            HKQuantitySample *sample = (HKQuantitySample *)[sampleObjects objectAtIndex:i];
            HKQuantity *quantity = sample.quantity;
            double bpm_Values= [quantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit unitFromString:@"count/min"]];
            sum_Of_HeartRates=sum_Of_HeartRates+bpm_Values;

        }
        avg_heartBeats=sum_Of_HeartRates/(int)sampleObjects.count;
    }];
    [heartQuery setUpdateHandler:^(HKAnchoredObjectQuery *query, NSArray<HKSample *> *SampleArray, NSArray<HKDeletedObject *> *deletedObjects, HKQueryAnchor *Anchor, NSError *error) {

        HKQuantitySample *sample = (HKQuantitySample *)[SampleArray objectAtIndex:0];
        HKQuantity *quantity = sample.quantity;
        new_Updated_Data =[quantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit unitFromString:@"count/min"]];
        NSLog(@"new quantity:%f",new_Updated_Data);
    }];
    [self.healthStore executeQuery:heartQuery];
    NSLog(@"updated data %f",new_Updated_Data);
    return avg_heartBeats;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try the code and let you know.

Comment: self.lastAnchor is undefined

Comment: You can use start date as anchor and it should work.

Comment: it doesn't - Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSDate *' to parameter of type 'HKQueryAnchor * _Nullable